# Error: The "target" property is no longer supported in next.config.js

Tags: typescript, next.js

> warn  - Invalid `next.config.js` options detected: 
> The root value has an unexpected property, target, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath, cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir, env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions, i18n, images, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output, outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader, productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactStrictMode, redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig, staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, trailingSlash, TypeScript, useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).
>
> Error: The "target" property is no longer supported in `next.config.js`.

This is my `next.config.js`

```
const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
  target: "serverless",
  env: {
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
  },

  webpack(conf) {
    conf.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "@svgr/webpack",
          options: {
            svgoConfig: {
              plugins: [
                {
                  // Enable figma's wrong mask-type attribute work
                  removeRasterImages: false,
                  removeStyleElement: false,
                  removeUnknownsAndDefaults: false,
                  // Enable svgr's svg to fill the size
                  removeViewBox: false,
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    conf.resolve.modules.push(__dirname);
    return conf;
  },
});
```

I thought it was a module issue so I reinstalled it but it was true. I tried following the format on the button link, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear:

```
Error: The "target" property is no longer supported in next.config.js.
```

The property `target: "serverless"` is deprecated in nextJs version 12, accordingly to this [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/41932#issuecomment-1294059022), the recommendation is to remove this property and use `output: "standalone"` instead.

See also, this [section](https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading#target-option-deprecated) in nextJs docs for more information about it.